# Why is vscode autocomplete tab value different from recommendation and how to fix?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, sveltekit

#### The Problem

I'm using [sveltekit](/questions/tagged/sveltekit) with [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) and VSCode as my editor.

Whenever I go to use `import`, autocomplete makes a recommendation. **The recommendation is correct:** `$lib/config`.

[image: autocomplete suggestion]

However, when I tab to complete, I'm given a different path. **The path is incorrect** and doesn't match the original recommendation: `\/config`.

[image: autocomplete tabbed]

---

#### My Settings

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
        "files": true
    },
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "paths": {
            //#region top level
            //lib
            "$lib": ["./src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"],
        },
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "typeRoots": ["@types/node"],
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "include": ["**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.js", "**/*.svelte", ".svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts"]
}
```

I've tried adding this option to my vscode settings (trying all values) as other posts recommended but it doesn't resolve the issue: `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier`.

---

#### Question

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? I should be getting `$lib/config` and not `\/config` when I tab.

Comment: what did you try setting `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` to? What do you observe for each value you set it to? Is there any different if you restart VS Code after changing the setting?

Comment: @user I tried all values. I get `../../lib/config` or `\/config`, never the correct value. Restarting does nothing.

Comment: This might just be a bug in the [language tools](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools), consider opening an issue (if nothing along the lines has been reported yet).